# Rails set scope for use in simple form association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form where I would like to associate new Invoices with Workorders that have a type (Workorder belongs_to Type) that is external (boolean field in type is called internal).

This is the code I would like to work:

```
<%= f.association :workorder, :collection => Workorder.external, :label_method => :wonum_desc, :label => 'Work Order' %>
```

So, I'm trying to set a scope called external in the workorder model.

This gives me 'undefined method internal':

```
scope :external, where(:type.internal => false)
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to includes the Type model and then add a conditions on the internal field of the Type table:

```
scope :external, includes(:type).where(types: { internal: false })
# notice the syntax:       ^^^^        ^^^^^
# in includes/joins, use the relation's name (here, Workoder belongs_to :type)
# in where, use the table's name (usually the pluralized version of the relation)
```